# Dudas en el modelado de Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Quiero implementar el que en una publicación que tiene su **Titulo**, **Descripción**, **IMG** **etc.** Si el usuario así lo desea, añada más **"Secciones"** o **"Pasos"** de información.

Mi duda entra aquí ¿Cómo debe ser el modelo de **publicacion** en Node para guardar esa información extra? No se si mi modelo está correcto.

Mi modelo:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const PublicacionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
        },
        secciones: {
            seccion: {
                titulo: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                descripcion: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                comentarios: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
                img: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
            }
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

PublicacionSchema.method('toJSON', function(){
    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();
    return object;
});


module.exports = model('Publicacion', PublicacionSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idealmente lo que estás tratando de hacer es darle la oportunidad a los usuario de agregar **varias** secciones. En ese caso tendría sentido que fuese un `Array` en lugar de un objeto. El `Schema` en cuestión quedaría:

```js
const PublicacionSchema = new Schema(
    {
        titulo: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        descripcion: {
            type: String,
            required: true, 
        },
        secciones: [{
             titulo: {
                 type: String,
                 required: true
             },
             descripcion: {
                 type: String,
                 required: true
             },
             comentarios: {
                 type: String,
                 required: true,
                },
             img: {
                 type: String,
                 required: true
             },
        }],
        img: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

Puedes hacer eso, o guardar una referencia de la sección creando un `Schema` nuevo llamado `Section`.

```js
sections: [
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Section', default: [] },
    ],
```

Solo tendrás que agregar [`ObjectIds`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) al `Array` de `sections`. Esto es beneficioso por varias razones, pero también tiene sus *weak points*. Tendrás que averiguar qué cubre mejor tus necesidades.

Comment: Increíble, muchas gracias por tan detallada respuesta.